# Получение имен содержащихся в контейнере объектов

Tags: ооп, объекты, delphi, delphi-7, классы

Есть следующий класс, содержащий информацию о базе данных

```
TDBSchemaSpec=class(Tcomponent)
  private
    FDomains: TComponent;
    FTables : TComponent;
  public
    procedure Setup();
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property Domains: TComponent read FDomains;
    property Tables : TComponent read FTables;
end;
```

В экземпляр класса `TDBSchemaSpec` свойство `Tables` становится контейнером для объектов `TTableSpec` (в цикле по записям таблицы со  списком таблиц)

```
  TableSpec:=TTableSpec.Create(DBSchema.Tables);
  DBSchema.Tables.InsertComponent(TComponent(TableSpec));
```

Как обойти все компоненты `TableSpec`, содержащиеся в `DBSchema.Tables` и получит их имена, если у  класса `TTableSpec` есть `public` свойство `Name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Классе `TComponent` есть свойство `Components`:

```
property Components [Index: Integer]: TComponent
```

Можно пройтись по нему и отобразить имена всех объектов в нём. Пример (при условии, что все дочерние компоненты это `TTableSpec`):

```
for i := 0 to dbSchemaSpec.Tables.ComponentCount-1 do
begin
  if dbSchemaSpec.Tables.Components[i] is TTableSpec then
    ShowMessage(TTableSpec(dbSchemaSpec.Tables.Components[i]).Name);
end;
```